# Rakefile for delayed_job with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rake, delayed-job

I want to use delayed_job with my Sinatra application, but I'm having trouble getting my rake file set up correctly.  When I run rake jobs:work, I get this:

```
rake aborted! 
Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'
```

I suspect I need to add a definition to my Rakefile to specify what it means to do jobs:work, but I can't find any documentation on how to do that.  It looks like delayed_job is usually used with Rails, and Rails seems to generate the appropriate rake definitions for you.

How can I set up my Rakefile to be able to run jobs:work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as you guessed, you have to setup your Rakefile and a little extra to do that. You can find a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/jerryjohnjacob/d308aff3738abc8355d9) on the same. Hope it solves your problem.